# How to pas a View Model object from a controller to another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to pass a view model object from one controller to another controller in ASP.net MVC4. I am getting an error "Cannot implicitly convert type object to ViewModel.studentDetailsViewmodel object". below is my code.

**View Model Class**

```
public class studentDetailsViewmodel 
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Age {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
public class StudentController : Controller
    {
       public ActionResult StudentInfo()
       {
        studentDetailsViewmodel studentDetails=new studentDetailsViewmodel();
        studentDetails.Name="safeer";
        studentDetails.Age="10";
        TempData["studentDetails"] = studentDetails;
       return RedirectToAction("DisplayStudentInfo", "Student");

       }
       public ActionResult DisplayStudentInfo()
       {
   studentDetailsViewmodel StudentDetailsModel= new   studentDetailsViewmodel();
      StudentDetailsModel = TempData["studentDetails"];

      return view("StudentInfo",StudentDetailsModel);

      }
}
```

I am getting an error "Cannot implicitly convert type object to ViewModel.studentDetailsViewmodel object"

Comment: Your naming convetion & formatting is a bit strange..

Comment: Error is telling you everything you need, you have to cast explicit object to studentDetailsViewmodel

Comment: steebchen . I am new to asking questions in stack over flow.Please don't discourage beginners like me :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 studentDetailsViewmodel StudentDetailsModel= 
      (studentDetailsViewmodel )TempData["studentDetails"];
```

You need to cast it.

Comment: first assignment is redundant :)

Comment: Right on, ty Resharper :)